# How to Create an XML Document in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, system.xml

I can't seem to figure out how to create a new XML file in SilverLight. I tried using XMLTextWriter and XMLDocument but on both I get the error "does not exist in the current context"

I'm using System.Xml and I can use XMLWriter and XMLReader but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Linq to Xml and the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class. Sample from MSDN:

```
XDocument srcTree = new XDocument(
    new XComment("This is a comment"),
    new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
        new XElement("Child2", "data2"),
        new XElement("Child3", "data3"),
        new XElement("Child2", "data4"),
        new XElement("Info5", "info5"),
        new XElement("Info6", "info6"),
        new XElement("Info7", "info7"),
        new XElement("Info8", "info8")
    )
);
```

This is using the  `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

You need to add a reference to the assembly `System.Xml.Linq.dll` in your Silverlight project:

[image]

Comment: tried XDocument too, SilverLight wouldn't let me use that or add the XML.Linq namespace.  :(

Comment: what silverlight version are you using? what do you mean by "it won't let you"?

Comment: It should be available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I mean that if I put in using System.Xml.Linq; It says "Linq" does not exist in the namespace System.Xml. I'm using Silverlight 5

Comment: @Blake: See update: You need to add a reference to the assembly where `XDocument` is defined in.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. You saved me from a huge headache and I really appreciate it.